# Streams approach for max integer in ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, functional-programming, hashmap, java-stream, concurrenthashmap

I have the following imperative programming code snippet here:

```
    Map<String, Integer> nameCounts = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    String mostCommon = null;
    int mostCommonCount = -1;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : nameCounts.entrySet()) {
        if (mostCommon == null || entry.getValue() > mostCommonCount) {
            mostCommon = entry.getKey();
            mostCommonCount = entry.getValue();
        }
    }
```

When executed with certain data, `nameCounts` should contain results such as:

```
nameCounts = {HashMap@795}  size = 6
 0 = {HashMap$Node@805} "William" -> "232818"
 1 = {HashMap$Node@806} "Dennis" -> "233249"
 2 = {HashMap$Node@807} "Maynard" -> "233205"
 3 = {HashMap$Node@808} "Vincent" -> "233288"
 4 = {HashMap$Node@809} "John" -> "234109"
 5 = {HashMap$Node@810} "Donald" -> "233331"
```

What is the functional approach by using Java 8's Streams I could use, to get the `String` with the highest value? (in this case, it would be "John").

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where's your ``ConcurrentHashMap`` ?

Comment: there it is @SchiduLuca

Comment: Specific for a `ConcurrentHashMap`, you can use `Map.Entry<String, Integer> maxEntry = nameCounts.reduceEntries(8, BinaryOperator.maxBy(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()));` (if the variable has been declared as `ConcurrentHashMap` rather than just `Map`). The first parameter (the eight in my example) specifies the desired number of threads. Otherwise, for general `Map` solutions, follow the link…